# Insert multiple shapes based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert rectangle shapes x amount of times based on cell input.

Example: cell a1 has 3 entered, make 3 rectangles, if cell a1 has 6 entered, make 6 rectangles.

Ideally, they would be within a parameter but I am not that far yet.

My code changes the dimensions of the rectangle based on cell input.

How can I add this to then reference a different cell to insert x amount of times?

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")

ws.Shapes.AddShape msoShapeRectangle, 50, 50, Range("E11"), Range("F11")

' added a loop but it is not selecting or reading the range correctly

Dim rge As range, cell As range
Set rge = range("A1")
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")

ws.Shapes.AddShape msoShapeRectangle, 50, 50, range("E11"), range("F11")

For Each cell In rge

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Since you need multiple shapes, have you tried using a loop?

Comment: I have not, I would assume I would have to tie the loop into the actual creation of the shape. so the loop would have to reference my cell (a1) after the shape is created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a regular `For` loop, not a `For Each`:

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 to rge.Value
    ws.Shapes.AddShape msoShapeRectangle, 50, 50, range("E11"), range("F11")
Next
```

Currently your `Range` calls are unqualified, i.e. they implicitly reference the `ActiveSheet`. I assume they should refer to `ws`.

Some other minor changes:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim rge As Range
Set rge = ws.Range("A1")

Dim width As Single
width = ws.Range("E11").Value

Dim height As Single
height = ws.Range("F11").Value

For i = 1 to rge.Value
    ws.Shapes.AddShape msoShapeRectangle, 50, 50, width, height
Next
```